# (Easier) way to determine determinant of a almost-circulant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Consider the matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix} \color{red}{-x+y} &-1&0&-1 \\ -1&\color{blue}{x+y}&-1&0 
\\ 0&-1&\color{red}{-x+y}&-1 \\ -1&0&-1&\color{blue}{x+y} \end{pmatrix}$$

**Is there any easy way to calculate the determinant of this matrix?**

I have read up on circulant matrices and there is some nice theory on them, however this is not quite circulant, the only difference is that the main diagonal contains 2 different values.

So I was wondering if there is a 'short cut' to find the determinant of these kind of *almost*-circulant matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are (at least) a few options:

1. For this particular matrix, row-reduction (to produce an upper-triangular matrix) is efficient.
2. This is a rank-$2$ update of a circulant matrix, so one can apply the [Matrix Determinant Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma).
3. Because of the special form of the matrix, one can use the special block matrix identity $$\det \pmatrix{A&B\\B&A} = \det(A + B) \det(A - B) .$$

Comment: would (1) and (2) work for any almost-circulant matrix? i.e. if we had a a sparse $8\times8$ matrix similar to the one above.

Comment: For a general circulant matrix, (1) could well involve many operations (naively, up to ${n - 1} \choose 2$, instead of the four operations for the given example), though probably one can exploit the circulant nature of the subdiagonal entries somehow to expedite this process. For (2), if the matrix has size $(2m) \times (2m)$, then one will need $m$ rank-$1$ updates, but these will all be computationally similar.

Comment: Of course, I mean "almost circulant" in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

Substract line two from line four and develop by first column (factoring out $\;x+y\;$ from last row):

$$\begin{vmatrix}-x+y&-1&0&-1\\-1&x+y&-1&0\\0&-1&-x+y&-1\\0&-x-y&0&x+y\end{vmatrix}=(-x+y)(x+y)\begin{vmatrix}x+y&-1&0\\-1&-x+y&-1\\-1&0&1\end{vmatrix}+$$

$$+(x+y)\begin{vmatrix}-1&0&-1\\-1&-x+y&-1\\-1&0&1\end{vmatrix}=$$$${}$$

$$=(y^2-x^2)\left(y^2-x^2-2\right)+(x+y)\left(2x-2y\right)=(y^2-x^2)(y^2-x^2-2)-2(y^2-x^2)=$$

$$=(y^2-x^2)(y^2-x^2-4)$$